# Simple Mail Confirmation in PHP

Tags: php, email, identity

What im basically trying to do is to confirm the identity of the user by using the mail address then Do certain database operation if the identity is verified.
I want to generate a confirmation code and send to the email address in the form of a URL.
But i do not want to maintain a database for the confirmation codes.How can i do this using encryption.Any Ideas?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in temporarily storing confirmation codes by the way. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Hash the email address in question with some secret salt and make that the token in the link. Then when you're verifying it, repeat that same process.

Comment: When verifying it, will he decode the variable in link? is it safe and secure that way ?

Comment: If security was more of a concern, I'd manage the tokens like the OP is wishing not to do. But he could have a secret salt that is server side used in creating the hashes. Seems secure to me.

Comment: I would not recommend this practice to handle lost passwords security keys for instance, but I guess it may be okay for email verification.

Comment: @Mahn, are you familiar with hashing? This is the exact scenario you'd use value+salt (obviously your salt is secret). It is how you verify the authenticity of data being presented by an untrusted source. It's an extremely common practice.

Comment: Yes I am, but it is still strictly speaking not the most secure method in that if an attacker figures out the secret salt and the algo used he could potentially generate his own keys (which is an unlikely scenario, but not impossible); whereas creating and storing a random key renders that (again unlikely) situation (nearly) impossible, since the "source" of the hash is then unknown to the attacker.

Comment: If the salt is discovered, then the attacker is privy to server side information and you have much larger problems on your hands. I however do agree that a unique token should be used for each individual user but the OP wants to avoid that in his/her situation. A popular practice is giving each user their own generated salt.

Comment: The attacker doesn't necesarily have to have server access, if the salt for instance is not unique, theoretically all it takes is one email address and its corresponding hash and he can just do some brute forcing to find out the salt.

Comment: what if you use the email (or part of it) in the secret salt itself.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a method of making the salt unique, which would definitively be better.

Comment: Anyway OP may not even need to care up to that level of security since probably the only risk here is an attacker verifying someone elses email.

Answer (score 2):

it should look like:

```
    <?php

    $salt = "this is a secret key!!!";

    if(isset($_GET["confirm"]) && isset($_GET["email"])){
        $confirm = $_GET["confirm"];
        $to_email = $_GET["email"];

        if(sha1($salt.$to_email) == $confirm){
            // this mail is confirmed, now do some db work
            // update_db ... ();
        }else{
            die("error: mail not confirmed");
        }


    }elseif(isset($_GET["email"])){
        $to_email = $_GET["email"];

        $confirm_link = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?confirm=".urlencode(sha1($salt.$to_email))."&mail=".urlencode($to_email);
        $msg = "to confirm ... click the link: \n ".$confirm_link;
        mail($to_email,"pls. confirm your mail",$msg);
    }else{
        die("error message");
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way of that is having a varchar field in your database named "activation".

So you can keep "confirmation code" there. When user has activated his account you will update it to "1". So if the field is "1"; User has activated his account. Otherwise there will be still confirmation code there and user's account is not activated. So there will be at least one column for activation process.